# Django testing view input with different character sets

Tags: django, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm having trouble trying to generate a test for my views. I've a view, that consumes in a given input from form, some characters. That characters are commited to DB, without problems.

All I was trying was to generate a test to ensure that different characters, from different languages, were accepted.

I tested this one:

Český jazyk neboli čeština

This input is correctly got from HTML form, and stored in DB. When I try to set this one from test, something weird happens, and view throws an error, saying that

Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x8Cesk\xC3...' for column 'title' at row 1

My code is as simple as follows:

```
str1 = "Český jazyk neboli čeština"
self.client.post(url, {"title": str1})
```

And tryied all combinations:

```
str1 = u"..."
str1 = str1.encode('utf-8')
str1 = str1.decode('utf-8')
```

Without any success.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Make sure you have included this at the beginning of your script:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

That is to tell the interpreter that this file's encoding is `utf-8` (make sure it is from your text editor)

Second: instead of

```
str1 = "Český jazyk neboli čeština"
```

declare the str1 as unicode like this:

```
str1 = u"Český jazyk neboli čeština"
```

Now, I'll suggest you that if you want to include non ascii chars, declare them with their proper unicode code instead of the character to avoid weird encoding issues.

```
str1 = u'\u010cesk\xfd jazyk neboli \u010de\u0161tina'
```

[This is a useful page to check characters unicode code](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first 2 steps were done. Anyway, the only one that I've not done is the last one (to set direct encoding to unicode). Is this mandatory? what about if that kind of strings are coming from an outside resource like a file (so, I can't write u'\u010cesk\xfd jazyk neboli \u010de\u0161tina' instead of u"Český jazyk neboli čeština")? is there any way to use this string u"Český jazyk neboli čeština" and encode it properly?

Comment: It is of course, It was just a suggestion. Just, get very clear what encoding you are using to write it and do it this way. `str=str.decode('<the encoded you used>')`. That will convert str to unicode and therefore you can use it to whatever you need with python. Real life example: Have a file encoded in utf-8 (you can check with your text editor) load it from python. `decode('utf-8')` it, and there you go :)